# How to display texture at any width height using css texture atlas

Tags: html, css

I have a texture atlas that is packed images at specified positions in a single image. I want to display these images at specified width height using css, (prefarably some percentage of parent width, height).

When I set the width and height it displays the packed image at original size, but I want it to display bigger, at given percentage width and height.

I've tried setting these properties but I couldn't control the display size of the image:

`background-size` `background-position` `background-image`, `width`, `height`.

```css
.sprite {
  background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/301/301');
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  background-position: -32px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sprite">

</div>
```

Comment: Would you elaborate what you want in detail?

Comment: For example I want the box in the example to scale to cover half of the page.

Comment: "half of the page" entire page you mean? I have created snippet from your question, can you explain considering that.

Comment: `width` is 32px which means take 32px from the original image, and display 32px size. But I want to take 32px from the original image, and display at for example 64px size. Or Prefabably 50% large of the parent container. like `width: 50%` doesn't work.

Comment: are you looking for repeat this pattern for entire div?

Comment: No I want to scale part of the image to be desired size.